# android multiple translate animations at once, make animations run slowly and with gap

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create an activity that contains multiple image galleries.
from each gallery the user can flip images out with translate animation.

The problem is that when the user tries to flip many images at once(I meab before the other flipping animations have ended), the animations become very gappy and slowly.

Does anyone knows how to show many animations in the same time, but still have them to go smooth?

Thank you guys

Edit:

Animation 1: X10

Animation 2: X10

Animation 3: X10

Animation 4: X10

Think of the following scenario: flying images(of birds) from left side to right side and back. It goes really slowy and gapy for me and I dont have a clue why. Thanks

Comment: anyone? I'm doing all the animations from the UI thread off course, on a view that contains just one imageView.